# MySQL date query

Tags: mysql

I want to make a query that will select a random row from a table that has the start date + time less than the current date.

This is what I have so far:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM premium 
        WHERE 
        DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= start_date 
        ORDER BY
        RAND() LIMIT 1 ";
```

I want to replace `30` with the value from the `time` column for each row.
How can I acces the `time` value for each row inside the query? (inside the interval)

Comment: does this work: `$query="SELECT * FROM premium WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL time DAY) <= start_date ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ";
`

Comment: Omg, I was so stupid... The column was named "timp" and not "time" ... sorry ;)) thanks . Post answear so I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM premium 
WHERE start_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL HOUR(start_date) DAY)  
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Or if your column is named `time` do

```
SELECT * FROM premium  
WHERE start_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL HOUR(`time`) DAY)  
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Don't forget to put backticks `` ` `` around time, because `time` is a reserved word.

Comment: I had to remove the "HOUR" conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the '$query' tag, I take it you're compiling this query in PHP? In that case, why not just generate the date tag in php? Something like this will work:

```
$date_before = date(<format>, time() - (30 × 24× 3600));
```

With '' being the way you want the date parsed (like 'Y-m-d H:i:s').

If you want to keep it in the query itself, you can use the NOW() function and do the same calculation, just this time inside the query.